# Using $groups to define TokenRegex rules

Tags: regex, stanford-nlp

I am trying to use TokenRegex to match pattern in my data but have been getting errors in the regex expression I am using. What is the right regex format to match $group followed by numbers. E.g my data may contain JIRA bug ticket number **JSON-123** or **SBP-32** etc. I would also like to extract some keywords associated with each ticket e.g authentication failure or  NullPointer Exception etc. What tool can I use in conjunction with TokenRegex to be able to extract these keywords as well. I looked at bootstrapped learning but am having a hard time implementing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);
    List<CoreLabel> tokens = new ArrayList<CoreLabel>();
    for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
        // **using TokensRegex**
        for (CoreLabel token : sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class))
            tokens.add(token);
        String $PROJECTID = "/JSON|JPA|SBP/";
        try {
            TokenSequencePattern p1 = TokenSequencePattern
                    .compile('('+$PROJECTID+'\\-\\d+)');
            TokenSequenceMatcher matcher = p1.getMatcher(tokens);

            while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println(matcher);
                matcheData.append(matcher);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Try using `String $PROJECTID = "(JSON|JPA|SBP)";` and then `System.out.println(matcher.group(2));`. Also, you do not have to escape the hyphen outside the character class.

Comment: @stribizhev. Shouldn't it be group 1?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes: I do not know what the *keyword* is. If it is *JSON*, or *JPA*, then it is Group 2. If *JSON-123* or *SBP-32*, then Group 0, no capturing groups are necessary.

Comment: Hi, I used `TokenSequencePattern p1 = TokenSequencePattern.compil('('+$PROJECTID+'-\\d+)');` but it still gives an error. And the keyword is the entire ticket number e.g. JSON-123

Comment: Try `String $PROJECTID = "(?:JSON|JPA|SBP)";` and then `System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); matcheData.append(matcher.group(0));`

Comment: So I'm running this in eclipse and it throws an error on the line `TokenSequencePattern p1 = TokenSequencePattern.compil('('+$PROJECTID+'-\\d+)');` I think this regex needs to be fixed.